# Can I make Orchard show the entirety of a blog post in the blog list?

Tags: content-management-system, orchardcms

I just set up Orchard and noticed that the preview widget only shows the first couple sentences with the standard "more" link. Is there a way to override this functionality without creating a custom widget? I would like Orchard to show the entirety of my latest five posts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, just put this Parts.Common.Body.Summary.cshtml in the views directory of your theme:

```
@{
    Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentItem contentItem = Model.ContentPart.ContentItem;
    var bodyHtml = new HtmlString(Model.Html.ToString());
}

<p>@bodyHtml</p>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. That was easy and awesome. I need to read more documentation, but I am just starting out with Orchard.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked for me, thought I had to edit in Core\Views since my theme didn't override it. I haven't found a better solution yet. I'm surprised this isn't an option in the configuration yet. It feels like it should be.

Comment: @bertrand le roy: how can I  put comments in blog list? I mean how to show comments bellow each post

Comment: Please ask new questions as new questions.

Answer (score 9):

I wanted to do something similar without overriding the Common.Body.Summary part for the whole site. I only wanted BlogPosts to use the full HTML for the Summary. I think I've accomplished this by adding the following line to Placement.info:

```
<Match ContentType="BlogPost">
    <Match DisplayType="Summary">
        <Place Parts_Common_Body_Summary="Content:after;Alternate=Parts_Common_Body"/>
    </Match>
</Match>
```

Comment: By adding the atrribute Path="/blog" to the Match element, I was able to show the full text of the post on the Blog page, while keeping short summaries in the home page widget.