# Manipulating BlogPost MetaData

Tags: orchardcms

After having followed the [instructions to "unabridge" blog posts in Orchard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056478/can-i-make-orchard-show-the-entirety-of-a-blog-post-in-the-blog-list), I'd now like to separate the blog post date and comment-count, so that the date appears ahead of the blog post, and the comment-count appears after.  How would that be done?

Even better, I'd additionally like to have the comment-count be a hyper link to the blog post detail.  How would that be done?

Answer (score 1):

To do this and many other similar things, you should enable shape tracing (it comes as part of the designer tools module). This will show you what template is rendering what, and also where they are positioned. It will also tell you what templates you can create in your theme to override behavior. The Model tab in particular will show you the whole model object graph and will give you the expression to put in your template to include any property into your markup.